# How to not call the database table if there is no new transaction happen on the table

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-actuator

I have a repository method to fetch records, and it gets called each time I hit a endpoint and it cost me more. 
I don't want to call the database table if there is no new transaction (`insert/update/delete`) happen. 
It should call database once and then wait for transaction to happen on the table then only fetch new records.

Tools: Java 8, JPA, Postgresql.

I read about `actuator refresh` but it reload all beans. I read about `@RefreshScope` which is used to refresh properties dynamically and I didn't get it how can I use them to achieve my goal.

Comment: Is this because you have tested and KNOW that there is a noticeable performance Hot, or just something that you think might be a good optimisation ?   I suspect the latter, In which case premature optimisation is rarely a good idea !  For example, are you aware that packages like Hibernate use caches precisely to minimise having to go to the database.

Comment: Yes, I am thinking to use hibernate second level cache to achieve this. The table rarely updated, that why I looking for optimization's. Is it good idea to implement cache here?

Comment: Again, premature optimisation is a bad idea.  Since Hibernate will already be catching it, I don’t see what great gains you expect to see.